# The Hollies ´ song

Tags: meaning

What´s the meaning of "*the early bird´s been up all morning*"  second verse of ***[I am down](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/hollies/imdown.html)***  by The Hollies.   Thank you

Comment: To be up = to be awake. Is he up yet? No, he's still asleep.

Answer (score 1):

In a figurative sense, **an early bird** is a person who wakes up early.

> -early bird - "an early riser, one that arrives early and especially before possible competitors" -  [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/early%20bird)

In the lyrics,most likely  it refers to somebody who woke up very early and has been busy all morning, but without more context it's hard to tell.

A well-known proverb: "The early bird catches the worm" (first Known Use: circa [1670, 1678](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/127000.html)), meaning "one who arrives early has the best chance for success".